# chart.js break line in a label with a tooltip callback

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

Working with chart.js in a vue.js component I was using a nested array to break line in my longs labels.
Since I use a tooltips callback  to add a % at the end of the labels they are not breaking line anymore.

```js
Vue.component('ethique-chart', {
  extends: VueChartJs.Doughnut,
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: [['Lutte contre la corruption', 'active ou passive'], ['Actions en faveur de la responsabilité', 'sociétale chez les fournisseurs'] ],
      datasets: [
        {
          
          backgroundColor: [ '#0075AA', '#258BB7'],
          data: [90, 7]
        }
      ]
    }, 
    
    {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false,legend: { display: false}, 
     animation: {
            duration: 3000, easing : 'easeInOutQuad'
        }, tooltips: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(231, 30, 116, .87)',
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      return data['labels'][tooltipItem['index']] + ': ' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']] + '%';
    }
  }
}
})
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure, the `label` callback function returns an `array` to make it work as expected. It could be written as follows:

```
callbacks: {
  label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
    let i = tooltipItem['index'];
    let label = data['labels'][i];
    return label.slice(0, -1).concat(label.slice(-1) + ': ' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][i] + '%');
  }
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code to see how it works. This is plain JavaScript but the `label` callback function will look the same with Vue.js.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [
      ['Lutte contre la corruption', 'active ou passive'],
      ['Actions en faveur de la responsabilité', 'sociétale chez les fournisseurs']
    ],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: ['#0075AA', '#258BB7'],
      data: [90, 7]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 3000,
      easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
    },
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(231, 30, 116, .87)',
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          let i = tooltipItem['index'];
          let label = data['labels'][i];
          return label.slice(0, -1).concat(label.slice(-1) + ': ' + data['datasets'][0]['data'][i] + '%');
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```